# Numbers are concatenated instead of added together

Tags: javascript

I need the two numbers to be added but somehow they are concatenated. Where am I doing it wrong?

```
var a;
var b;
var parsedInta;
var parsedIntb;

a=window.prompt("enter your first number");
b=window.prompt("enter your second number");
parsedInta=parseInt(a);
parsedIntb=parseInt(b);

alert("The Sum is" + parsedInta+parsedIntb);
```

It concatenates the result rather than addition.

Comment: Simple answer is: Order of operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to introduce parentheses to force the numeric addition to happen before the alert string is built:

```
alert("The Sum is " + (parsedInta + parsedIntb));
```

Without the parentheses, the `+` operator is naturally left-associative, so the first "addition" carried out is the string concatenation between "The Sum is" and the first value (which is treated as a string).

*edit* — note that the `+` operator *prefers* string concatenation over numeric addition. If either operand of `+` is a string, then the other operand is converted to a string and the two are concatenated.

Comment: but why the first vale is treated as string when i did the parseInt?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini it is treated as a string because the `+` operator *prefers* string concatenation over numeric addition. So the first `+` operates on the introductory string and the first numeric value (parsedInta).  Because there's a string involved, it converts the number *back* to a string!

Answer (score -1):

This is beacuse the + operator is used also to do string concatenation. Since in your `"The Sum is" + parsedInta+parsedIntb` you are working with a string the language thinks you want to use parseinta and parseintb as strings.

You can solve by simply doing the sum before the string creation:

```
var sum  = parseInta + parseIntb;
alert("The Sum is" + sum);
```

Or also by using parseInt directly in the sum line:

```
var sum = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
alert("The Sum is" + sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

The probleme is that you are doing implicit type casting using "+" operator which will convert the number to string so your code will be like :

```
alert("the sum is "+number1+number2); //The number 1 will be converted to a string
,the same for the second number
```

So if i enter 10 in the first prompt and 10 in the second prompt the alert will show : the sum is 1010 because the first 10 is converted to a string and the second 10 will be converted to a string
**But** if i use parenthese like :

```
 alert("the sum is "+(number1+number2));
```

Here the two number will be added and it will be coverted to a string **after** the addition.
P.S : don't use window object because it's a global object so you can ignore it
And sorry for my bad english i hope that you will understand

Answer (score -3):

This is JavaScript. Don't expect the language to make sense.

---

This is because the `+` operator is overloaded for strings. If either of its operands is a string, `+` will turn the other operand into a string and concatenate them.

Since this awful operator is also left-associative, you will get

```
("The Sum is" + parseInta) + parsedIntb
```

which is a string plus a number (which is a string) plus a number, which is also a string.

Parenthesize the rightmost addition instead:

```
alert("The Sum is" + (parsedInta + parsedIntb));
```

And maybe consider starting to learn programming with a sane language.

Comment: Good explanation but I don't think your editorial comments about the sanity of Javascript are very helpful.

Comment: @MatthewNichols No problem, you don't have to agree with me on everything.